# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 60, 1), found shape=(None, 61, 1)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

Problem statement :  I have a dataset that conatains minute level count of flight tickets sold. The format looks like this :

```
"datetime","count"
"2022-09-29 00:00:00",273
"2022-09-29 00:01:00",265
```

My model trains with LSTM (it's a sample code - without the complexity). When I run the predict method , It keeps giving me this error. :

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 60, 1), found shape=(None, 61, 1)`

Here is my full code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


# Load data
df = pd.read_csv("training_data.csv", parse_dates=['datetime'], index_col='datetime')

# Split data into training and testing sets
train_size = int(len(df) * 0.8)
train_data, test_data = df.iloc[:train_size], df.iloc[train_size:]

# Normalize the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(train_data)
test_scaled = scaler.transform(test_data)

# Define function to create sequences
def create_sequences(data, seq_length):
    X, y = [], []
    for i in range(len(data)-seq_length):
        X.append(data[i:i+seq_length])
        y.append(data[i+seq_length])
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

# Create sequences
seq_length = 60
train_X, train_y = create_sequences(train_scaled, seq_length)
test_X, test_y = create_sequences(test_scaled, seq_length)

# Define LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(seq_length, 1)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#model.add(LSTM(32))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))

# Compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Train model
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=2, batch_size=1, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=1)

# Save model
model.save('lstm_model.h5')

# Make prediction
def make_prediction(date_time):
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('lstm_model.h5')
    date_time = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    data = df.loc[date_time - pd.Timedelta(minutes=seq_length):date_time]
    data_scaled = scaler.transform(data)
    X = np.array([data_scaled])
    y_pred = model.predict(X)
    return scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred)[0][0]

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    date_time = request.form['date_time']
    prediction = make_prediction(date_time)
    return {'prediction': prediction}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the curl command I use to call predict :

```
curl -X POST -F "date_time=2022-10-01 12:00:00" http://localhost:5000/predict
```

Please help !
Appreciate any time you are spending on my problem :-)